# Cypress - How to return the new value from .then()?

Tags: javascript, cypress

So, I am using Cypress and I want to change the value from the variable. Look at my script below:

```js
let bankBranch = Base Data;
 
cy.get("#bankBranch").then(() => {
  bankBranch = bankBranch.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
}).type(bankBranch);
```

I want Cypress to type it as "Base+Data". But, it still typing "Base Data".

How to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to understand that Cypress commands run asynchronously from the javascript in the test.

Move the `.type()` inside the `.then()` so it happens after you modify the value

```js
let bankBranch = 'Base Data';

cy.get("#bankBranch").then($el => {
  bankBranch = bankBranch.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
  cy.wrap($el).type(bankBranch)
})
```

There are other refactors, I recommend playing around.

```js
// replace the space early
let bankBranch = 'Base Data'.replace(/\s+/g, '+')

cy.get("#bankBranch")
  .type(bankBranch)
```

```js
let bankBranch = 'Base Data';

cy.get("#bankBranch").then($el => {
  bankBranch = bankBranch.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
  // pass on the element
  return $el
}).then($el => {
  // deferring the .type() command
  cy.wrap($el).type(bankBranch)
})
```